# Need an explanation for the gridview sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview

As I'm new to .NET, I need the explanation for the following code. Can anyone give me the explanation?

```
protected void GridView1_Sort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    GridView grid = sender as GridView;

    DataTable dt = Session["List"] as DataTable;
    string month = System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).ToString("MMMM");
    if (dt != null)
    {
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " +     GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
        grid.DataSource = Session["List"];
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: ...Which part, exactly? What is it you don't understand about it?

Comment: This is not an "explain my code" site ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is normally not an "explain my code" site...

Grid [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort.aspx) method: Sorts the GridView control based on the specified sort expression and direction.

```
protected void GridView1_Sort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
```

Casting the sender to the GridView. The sender is always the control that raised an event.

```
GridView grid = sender as GridView;
```

Get the DataSource of the `GridView` from `session` since it was stored there on a previous request. Note that all objects are disposed at the end of every page's lifecycle, so you need to persist it somewhere(Session,ViewState) or load it again from your rdbms(recommended).

```
DataTable dt = Session["List"] as DataTable;
```

The following line is redundant and can be deleted

```
string month = System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).ToString("MMMM");
```

I  assume that the old direction was stored in ViewState/Session and that the `GetSortDirection` method reverses the sort-direction(DESC if it was sorted ASC on that column before and so on).

```
string month = System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).ToString("MMMM");
if (dt != null)
{
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " +     GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression); // i assume that the old direction
```

Store it again in Session and databind the `GridView`.

```
        grid.DataSource = Session["List"];
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it is not an explain my code site. Since im new to this .net. I donno what it is doing. Thanks alot for your explaination. Particularly this one                               dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " +     GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);